# On the Spectral Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $T\in B(H)$ be normal and $E$ its spectral measure.
>
> a- Let $\delta >0$ , and let $M_{\delta}$ = $\left\{\lambda\in \sigma(T): |\lambda|\geq \delta\right\}$. Prove that $Range(E(M_{\delta}))\subseteq T(H)$.
>
> b- Let $\sigma\subseteq \sigma(T)$ be open then $E(\sigma)\neq 0$.
>
> c- Use the spectral theorem to prove that $T$ is positive $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\langle Tx,x\rangle \geq0$ , for all $ x\in H$.

Note we say $T$ is positive if there exists $S\in B(H)$ self-adjoint such that $T=S^2$.

Any idea how to start?
Thank you .

Comment: What is your working definition of positive? Most often, the equivalence of c is the actual definition.

Comment: @julien, we use the definition of positive elements in general $C^*$ algebra ; $T$ is positive iff $T=S^2S$ for some self adjoint $S$

Comment: @julien Oh yes, you're right, I fix it. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a-** Note that $1_{M_\delta}(x)=x\cdot 1_{M_\delta}(x)\cdot \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)1_{M_\delta}(x) =f_1(x)f_2(x)f_3(x).$ Applying the$L^\infty$ functional calculus of $T$, this yields
$$
E(M_\delta)=1_{M_\delta}(T)=f_1(T)f_2(T)f_3(T)=TE(M_\delta)f_3(T).
$$
Now clearly the range of the latter is contained in the range of $T$.

**b-** This is false, as $\sigma=\emptyset $ yields $E(\sigma)=0$. But it is true of $\sigma $ is a nonempty open set. Indeed, by the spectral theorem 
$$\|E(\sigma)\|=\|1_\sigma(T)\|=\|1_\sigma\|_\infty=1$$
in this case, hence $E(\sigma)\neq 0$.

**c-** If $T$ is positive, i.e. $T=S^2$ for some self-adjoint $S$, then $(Tx,x)=(S^2x,x)=(Sx,Sx)=\|Sx\|^2\geq 0$ for every $x$. Now assume $(Tx,x)\geq 0$ for every $x$. First show that $T$ is self-adjoint using polarization. Then check the spectrum of $T$ is nonnegative. By functional calculus, we can then set $S:=\sqrt{T}$, so that $S$ is self-adjoint and $S^2=T$.

**Note:** the if direction of c is false in the real case. Consider
$$
\left( \matrix{0&1\\-1&0}\right)
$$
for example.

Comment: is the part $f_1(T)f_2(T)f_3(T)$ how to conclude that range $E(M_\delta)$ is contained in range of $T$ thank you.

Comment: So $E(M_\delta)$ is written $T$ times something. So its range must be contained is the range of $T$.

Comment: so is this the follwoing correct, if $S=TW$ then range $S$ is contained in range $T$ (how about range of $W$), also how did you conclude that $\|1_{\sigma}(T)\|=\|1_\sigma\|_\infty$

Comment: Yes. $Sx=TWx=Ty\in\mbox{Im}T$ for every $x$. The spectral theorem says in particular that the functional calculus is isometric. That's how you compute the norm of $f(T)$. It's simply $\|f\|_\infty$.

Comment: Sorry julien, but I'm confused now, because we proved in class that the map between $B(\sigma(T))$ and $B(H)$ is * homomorphism,i.e multiplicative, the operation isn't the composition but the product!

Comment: The pointwise product on $B(\sigma(T))$, the composition on $B(H)$. Example: $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2+1$, yield $h(x)=f(x)g(x)=x^3+x$. So $h(T)=T^3+T=T(T^2+I)$. The operator notation $T(T^2+I)$ is a shortcut for $T\circ (T^2+I)$. I think that's where your confusion comes from. The product of two operators $ST$ is actually $S\circ T$.

Comment: Mmmmm, Thank you ! can you help me please with this question and tell me if my proof is correct ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362842/c-algebra-of-bounded-borel-functions