# C* algebra of bounded Borel functions

Tags: measure-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $T\in B(H)$ is normal, and $B(\sigma(T))$ denote the $C^*$ algebra of all bounded Borel functions on $\sigma(T)$. Then is it true that $B(\sigma(T))$ is a closed $C^*$ algebra under the sup. norm ?

Actually I try to prove the Spectral representation Theorem of a normal operator in case the representation of $C^*(T)$ over $H$ is cyclic, i.e there exists $x\in H$ such that $\{\phi(T)x:T \in C^*(T)\}$ is dense in $H$. We have $E$ is the the spectral measure of $T$, and $\mu$ is the positive regular Borel measure $\langle E(\cdot)x,x\rangle$ . So I define the following map $$ U\colon \{F(T)x: F\in B(\sigma(T))\}\rightarrow L_{2}(\mu) $$ by $U(F(T)x)=F$. I proved that the map $U$ is well defined and isometric. I want to prove that it has a dense range and can be extended to a unitary map on $H$. To prove the fist assertion I said that the $S$:the set of all simple functions on $\sigma(T)$ is contained in $B(\sigma(T))$, and hence the closure of $S$ under the sup. norm is contained in the closure of $B(\sigma(T))$. Hence the $C(\sigma(T))\subset  B(\sigma(T))$, but $C(\sigma(T))$ is dense in $L_{2}(\mu)$, which proves that $U$ has a dense range? Is that correct?

I'm stuck with the second assertion , so can you help me please! Thank you.

Comment: I think the fact that $C(\sigma(T))\subset B(\sigma(T))$ is enough to prove that $U$ has dense range!

Comment: For the second assertion, I think it's enough to prove that $\{F(T)x:F\in B(\sigma(T))\}$ is dense in $H$, but I'm not sure how to do that!

Comment: @julien, we are given this map and we are supposed to prove it's isometric well defined with dense range, and also can be extended to a unitary operator on $H$. I know that for a normal operator $T$ with spectrul measure $E$, we can define a * homomorphism $J$ from $B(\sigma(T))$ into $B(H)$ by : $J(f)=f(T)$, where $f(T)$ is given by the integral over the $\sigma(T)$ of $f(\lambda)E(d\lambda)$. So I used this theorem to prove that our map is norrm preserving and well defined

Comment: @julien, what I actually need to prove is:  why I can extend $U$? If I know why, I can solve the question completely.

Comment: $U$ is an isometry on a dense subset, namely $C^*(T)x$. So it extends uniquely to $H$.

Comment: So it's enough to consider $C(\sigma(T))x \subset B(\sigma(T))x$, as $C(\sigma(T))x$ is isomorphic to $C^*(T)x$, right?

Comment: Note that you need to add @myname if you want me to be notified. And yes, that's right. You can do shorter than my previous comment. So $U$ extends to an isometry $H\longrightarrow L^2$ and the range contains $L^\infty$, which is dense in $L^2$. Since the range of an isometry is closed, we're done.